# Access C# variable from in JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am learning ASP.net,
I have a variable in the code behind in c#:

```
public int hasCar= 1;
```

and in the aspx file I want to access this variable in javascript function:

```
function PrintCar( ) {
    var ind = <%=this.hasCar%>
    alert(ind);
}
```

but  I get error:

> does not contain a definition for 'hasCar' and no extension method 'hasCar' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.vids_aspx' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

what is wrong?

thank you

Comment: Where exactly are you defining the PrintCar fn in the code..

Comment: Looks like the javascript code's .aspx is not using your codebehind-file as codebehind, or you forgot to build your project.

Comment: in the end of the body. there i put <script type="text/javascript">code </script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to offer a complimentary answer rather than simply copying what other people have said. Personally I write JS from my C# rather than putting markup in the aspx.

I use this extension method:

```
public static class ClientScriptManagerExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Registers an object as a variable on the page
        /// </summary>
        public static void RegisterObjectAsVariable(this ClientScriptManager mgr, Type type, string variableName, object objectToEncode)
        {
            mgr.RegisterClientScriptBlock(type,
                string.Concat("ClientScriptManagerExtensions_", variableName),
                string.Concat("var ", variableName, " = ", new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(objectToEncode), ";"),
                true);
        }
    }
```

Then to call I do:

```
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterObjectAsVariable(typeof(MyPage), "myVariable", new { myProperty = 123});
```

This creates a js object on your page:

```
var myVariable = 
{
 myProperty = 123
};
```

Which you can access via JS. I find this approach much cleaner and it lets you pass all sorts of complex objects to your code.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

**ASPX Page:**

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function PrintCar( ) {
            var ind = <%=this.HasCar%>
            alert(ind);
        }
    </script>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="PrintCar();"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

**Code Behind**

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public int HasCar { get; set; }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HasCar = 1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you the following line at start line of your .aspx page ?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="YOURNAMESPACE._default" %>
```

Comment: yes I have this line, and still I try all the solutions here and it's not work. (I didn't try to call the JS from the code behind..cause I want to learn this method first)

Answer (score 0):

I have created test project just for your problem.

Try this code

Aspx Code..

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="test.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function PrintCar() {
            var ind = <%=this.HasCar%>;
            alert(ind);
        }
    </script>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="PrintCar()"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code behind...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace test
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public int HasCar { get; set; }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HasCar = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd be interested to know why this was downvoted - looks ok to me!